# Unable to add google_sign_in to flutter project, package requires older version of Flutter SDK?

Tags: flutter, google-signin

New to Flutter so sorry about the question. Tried to change the environment but project won't build.

```
The current Flutter SDK version is 1.9.1+hotfix.6.



Because solemaster depends on google_sign_in >=4.0.16 which requires Flutter SDK version 
>=1.10.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1)

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flutter SDK version you're using is older than the required by the library. You're confusing the Flutter SDK with the Dart SDK. The Dark SDK is the environment on the code you provided.

`google_sign_in` is based on the Flutter beta channel, instead of the stable channel. (p.s. this channel is where you get your flutter updates from).

From there, **you have two options**:

1. **Use an older version of `google_sign_in`**. Version 4.0.15 or 4.0.14 should do the trick, since this change was published today [as said on the changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in#-changelog-tab-).
   On the pubspec.yaml file, change the current declaration to `google_sign_in: 4.0.15`.
2. **Change to the beta channel**. Keep in mind that the Flutter versions here are being tested, so you may experience some issues. To change channel, run `flutter channel beta`, then `flutter upgrade`.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
flutter pub cache repair
flutter clean
```

Comment: Could you explain why this would potentially solve the problem? Especially because there is already another answer with a detailed explanation of the problem.